# Unable get the value from delegate swift

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, protocols

i am new to ios development and swift. i got stuck with one issue.please help me sort out this problem.I am using one custom date picker in that i am using two labels , labels name are  fromDateLbl and toDateLbl .i am using two buttons fromDateBtn and toDateBtn. i am able to get date if i use one label and one button not able get dates for two buttons.

see following my code.

```
    import UIKit

    class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet var fromDateLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet var toDateLabel: UILabel!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }
        @IBAction func fromDateAction(_ sender: Any) {

            let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomDatePickerViewController") as! CustomDatePickerViewController
            self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
            self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
            popOverVC.view.frame = view.bounds
            popOverVC.delegate = self as? CustomDatePickerDelegate
            popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        }        
    }
    @IBAction func toDateAction(_ sender: Any) {

            let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomDatePickerViewController") as! CustomDatePickerViewController
            self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
            self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
            popOverVC.view.frame = view.bounds
            popOverVC.delegate = self as? CustomDatePickerDelegate
            popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        }


    }


    extension SecondViewController:CustomDatePickerDelegate
    {
        func CustomDateSeletced(value: String) {
            fromDateLabel.text = value

        }

    }
```

secondVc code .

```
class CustomDatePickerViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!

    var delegate: CustomDatePickerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.frame.size.height =  UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
    }


    @IBAction func saveDateAction(_ sender: Any) {

        myDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
        let saveDate = dateFormatter.string(from: myDatePicker.date)
        print("selectedDate",saveDate)
        delegate?.CustomDateSeletced(value: saveDate)
        self.removeAnimate()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false

    }
```

this is my delegate class.

```
import Foundation

protocol  CustomDatePickerDelegate {
        func CustomDateSeletced(value: String)
}
```

Comment: can you explain where you are not able to get date value?

Comment: Where is the code for the second button click?

Comment: @ Vinaykrishnan i have updated my code please check it now.

Comment: @rohi i have to show date  according button click . if i select frombtn action i have to show from date .  if i select todatebtn action i have to show todate .

Comment: @vasu k, is action for both from and to date is same which is saveDateAction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the perfect solution but code below might help you. 
To improve little bit, You can use UILabel actions and remove UIButtons and store edited label, this way you can prevent UILabel editing also.

[Phillip Mills](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49407988/948445) implemented a better solution for you.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var fromDateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var toDateLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var fromDateButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var toDateButton: UIButton!

    var selectedButton: UIButton?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    @IBAction func selectDateAction(_ sender: Any) {
        selectedButton = sender as? UIButton

        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomDatePickerViewController") as! CustomDatePickerViewController
        self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
        popOverVC.delegate = self as? CustomDatePickerDelegate
        present(popOverVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }


}

extension SecondViewController:CustomDatePickerDelegate
{
    func CustomDateSeletced(value: String) {
        if let button = selectedButton {
            if button == toDateButton {
                toDateLabel.text = value
            } else {
                fromDateLabel.text = value
            }
            selectedButton = nil
        }

    }

}
```

-

```
@IBAction func saveDateAction(_ sender: Any) {

    myDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
    let saveDate = dateFormatter.string(from: myDatePicker.date)
    delegate?.CustomDateSeletced(value: saveDate)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: i tried your code i am able to see in console , in lables its not showing.

Comment: Do you call "self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)" somewhere? You can trigger it in "saveDateAction"

Comment: updated usage, seems like you do not remove picker from screen.

Answer (score 0):

Because your delegate doesn't remember why it called the picker, you have a situation where a delegate protocol may not be the best solution.  Here's a much-simplified version of how you could do this using closures instead.  It's a strategy that allows the picker to know specifically what to do with the value it generates.

```
class Second {
    @IBOutlet var fromDateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var toDateLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func fromDateAction(_ sender: Any) {
        // Setup popover as before
        let picker = Picker()
        picker.useCompletion { (returnedDate) in
            self.fromDateLabel.text = returnedDate
        }
    }

    @IBAction func toDateAction(_ sender: Any) {
        // Setup popover as before
        let picker = Picker()
        picker.useCompletion { (returnedDate) in
            self.toDateLabel.text = returnedDate
        }
    }
}

class Picker {
    var completion: ((String)->())?

    func useCompletion(_ block: @escaping (String)->()) {
        completion = block
    }

    @IBAction func saveDateAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let saveDate = "The text you want to return"
        if let completion = completion {
            completion(saveDate)
        }
    }

}
```